# IllegalArgumentException in Retrofit / must not have replace block / Dynamic Url / Retrofit 2

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I have the following code:

```
interface WeatherApi {
    @GET("/v1/forecast.json?key=**********&q={state}&days=4")
    fun getWeather(@Query("state") state: String): Single<Weather>
}
```

According to the official docs, I must use `@Query`, and I'm using it, but I'm getting the following error:

> URL query string "key=************&q={state}&days=4" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use this code

```
interface WeatherApi {
    @GET("/v1/forecast.json")
    fun getWeather(@Query("key") key: String,@Query("q") state: String,@Query("days") days: Int): Single<Weather>
}
```